# FindMaximum / Objective function contains an exogenous variable

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'd appreciate advice on the following simple maximization problem:

max_x f(x,y), where y=g(x) but y is taken as exogenous in objective function f(x,y).

Eventually, I am interested in x*(g(x*)). Is there a possibility to solve this kind of problems numerically (e.g., by using FindMaximum)?

The above, of course, is the simplest (I think) representation of the problem I am currently facing. The complete optimization model, I am working on, exhibits probably 1000 choice variables (like x) and probably 200 "exogenous" variables (like y), where all the y depend on all the x variables (like y=g(x)), and indirectly, all the x variables (first-order conditions f_x(x,y)) depend on the y variables.

A minimum code is here:

```
Minimum Example (FindMaximum)

Objective function W, choice variables x1, x2, and a constraint 

Clear["Global`*"]; 
W = u1 + 2*u2; u1 = Log[x1/2 + Delx10/2]; 
u2 = Log[x2/2 + Delx20/2]; 
constraint = 10 - x1 - x2; Delx1 = x1 - xb; 
Delx2 = x2 - xb; 
xb = (1/4)*x1 + (3/4)*x2; 

What I am NOT interested in

Comment. I am not interested in this case, b/c here, Delx10, Delx20 are endogenous variables in the objective function. But this case helps to see what I am after: the case for which Delx10, Delx20 are considered as exogenous, at the point of finding maximizing choices of x1, x2 (obviously depending on Delx10, Delx20).

In[193]:=
W1 = W /. {Delx10 -> Delx1, Delx20 -> Delx2}; 
FindMaximum[{W1, constraint == 0}, {{x1, 5}, {x2, 5}}]

Out[194]=
{2.7601661163974147, {x1 -> 4.777788184566904, 
   x2 -> 5.222211529375001}}

What I AM interested in

In[195]:=
W2 = W; 
FindMaximum[{W2, constraint == 0}, {{x1, 5}, {x2, 5}}]

Comment. Of course, this does not work, as the objective function contains variables, which FindMaximum cannot handle (or not the way I try to set up the maximization problem).
```

Comment: Please give a minimum example of code you've tried. Also if $y=g(x)$, then $y$ is endogenous as it depends on $x$ and the model - you must therefore fully express $y$ in terms of $x$ in the maximization. Exogenous variables are usually things like constants / parameters set up outside of the model and you must set them up beforehand. You cannot numerically maximize $f(x,y)$ if it contains a symbol (even if it represents a constant) $y$ without providing a value.

Comment: @flinty Thank you. Please find a minimum code here: [link](https://static.uni-graz.at/fileadmin/_Persoenliche_Webseite/wendner_ronald/Minimum_Example.nb).

Comment: @flinty And of course, in this minimum example, one can easily solve everything analytically (with Maximize) or by hand. Both, however, are not a possibility for the "big" model.

Comment: You should post that code here in the question. Note you can combine the sum of logarithms as a product in your objective and then remove the logarithm because it's monotone. You can put it back after finding the `{x1,x2}` --- `FindMaximum[{(x1/2 + Delx10/2) (x2/2 + Delx20/2)^2 /. {Delx10 -> 
     Delx1, Delx20 -> Delx2}, constraint == 0}, {{x1, 5}, {x2, 5}}]` Also if we assume for any given `{Delx10,Delx20}` there is a maximizing pair `{x1,x2}`, then we have a function we could visualize with random points, and show the line constraint.

Comment: External link can be broken. For the benefit of users of this site please provide a self-contained question.

Comment: @yarchik Thank you, I try to do this (converting cell in Raw InputForm) but it does not look well. Also, I do not see help on this on SE. But this is my first day, and I have to learn these things. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: There are formatting tips on top of the window (where you type question). See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @flinty I think it is easy to manipulate the objective function the way you suggest. However, this is not really addressing my problem. Exists there a "kind of" numerical optimization routine that allows me to keep a variable exogenous (and impacting) in my optimization problem, while being endogenous, AFTER optimization?

Comment: No there isn't. The only thing I can suggest is examine the derivatives of your problem. That's why I suggested manipulating the objective - it makes taking the gradient simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I fully agree.